# How to add integer column with default of unix timestamp (epoch) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: datetime, postgresql, epoch

This doesn't work:

```
create table event (
...
time int default date_part('epoch', timestamp 'now'),
...
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no postgresql expert but shouldn't this one work

```
time int default date_part('epoch', now())
```

Comment: Or with a bit more modern syntax - "atime INTEGER DEFAULT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)".

Comment: my editor changed the comment above to date_part('epoch'::text, now()) automatically, so I guess that's the 2020 modern version.